Different trajectory in Gazebo vs RViz
I found some strange Gazebo behavior that might contribute to my inability to perform fusion. If my robot is programmed to run in a circle, and according to independent (from Gazebo) test, it IS a circle, then: Gazebo trajectory is half circle, while RViz trajectory as an expected full circle.
So Gazebo (classic) simulation sends correct trajectory to RViz, but draws the wrong trajectory itself. What can it be?
Edition: It works fine on a straight line. It fails when turning. The robot is 4 wheeled dif. drive, so it is all about slippage.
So, is there a way to make Gazebo and RViz show the robot in same position, regardless the slippage?
